# Driver with tag "Stor" on Windows XP (32 bit)

Tags: windows-xp, memory, drivers

I have a leaking driver (leaks 40-60MB/day) on Windows XP (32 bit).  I used poolmon.exe from Server2003 SP2 (file-date is in 2007), I get:

Stor Nonp 169527 ( 13) 950 ( 0) 168577 49377328 ( 3744) 292 Unknown Driver

After hours of googling and searching my *.sys files for strings, I am still not able to identify this driver.  Has anybody encountered it?

TIA, Radim

Here is "driverquery /V" output:

```
Module Name  Display Name           Description            Driver Type   Start Mode State      Status     Accept Stop Accept Pause Paged Pool Code(bytes BSS(by Link Date              Path                                             Init(bytes
============ ====================== ====================== ============= ========== ========== ========== =========== ============ ========== ========== ====== ====================== ================================================ ==========
ACPI         Microsoft ACPI Driver  Microsoft ACPI Driver  Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        41,984.00  110,336.00 0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:33    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ACPI.sys             4,864.00  
ACPIEC       ACPIEC                 ACPIEC                 Kernel        Disabled   Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        1,536.00   4,352.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:57:55    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ACPIEC.sys           1,152.00  
ADPUSBLD     Adaptec USB2-Xchange F Adaptec USB2-Xchange F Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       1,696.00   0.00   2002-05-20 21:56:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\Adpusbld.sys         480.00    
ADPUSBMS     Adaptec USB2-Xchange M Adaptec USB2-Xchange M Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        7,104.00   5,248.00   0.00   2002-05-15 02:28:18    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\Adpusbst.sys         1,568.00  
aec          Microsoft Kernel Acous Microsoft Kernel Acous Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        69,376.00  6,016.00   0.00   2007-05-24 15:53:32    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\aec.sys              2,176.00  
AFD          AFD Networking Support AFD Networking Support Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        111,488.00 4,096.00   0.00   2008-08-14 06:04:35    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\afd.sys              8,448.00  
agp440       Intel AGP Bus Filter   Intel AGP Bus Filter   Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        25,728.00  8,960.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:37    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\agp440.sys           2,688.00  
Arp1394      1394 ARP Client Protoc 1394 ARP Client Protoc Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       53,504.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:51:22    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\arp1394.sys          1,792.00  
AsyncMac     RAS Asynchronous Media RAS Asynchronous Media Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       9,216.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:57:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\asyncmac.sys         1,280.00  
ati2mtag     ati2mtag               ati2mtag               Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        204,800.00 1,003,520. 0.00   2005-11-22 22:50:49    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ati2mtag.sys         8,192.00  
Atmarpc      ATM ARP Client Protoco ATM ARP Client Protoco Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       48,256.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:51:24    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\atmarpc.sys          3,456.00  
audstub      Audio Stub Driver      Audio Stub Driver      Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        512.00     128.00     0.00   2001-08-17 16:59:40    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\audstub.sys          384.00    
AvgLdx86     AVG Free AVI Loader Dr AVG Free AVI Loader Dr Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        512.00     199,936.00 0.00   2009-05-21 04:53:01    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\avgldx86.sys         4,096.00  
AvgMfx86     AVG Free On-access Sca AVG Free On-access Sca File System   System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        768.00     12,480.00  0.00   2009-06-06 23:38:40    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\avgmfx86.sys         3,712.00  
AvgTdiX      AVG Free8 Network Redi AVG Free8 Network Redi Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        256.00     80,256.00  0.00   2009-04-06 09:42:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\avgtdix.sys          3,072.00  
BCMModem     BCM V.92 56K Modem     BCM V.92 56K Modem     Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        16,640.00  750,848.00 0.00   2003-08-27 23:05:02    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\BCMSM.sys            3,840.00  
Beep         Beep                   Beep                   Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       1,152.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:47:33    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Beep.sys             768.00    
cbidf2k      cbidf2k                cbidf2k                Kernel        Disabled   Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       11,008.00  0.00   2001-08-17 16:52:06    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\cbidf2k.sys          640.00    
CCDECODE     Closed Caption Decoder Closed Caption Decoder Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        256.00     11,904.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:46:22    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\CCDECODE.sys         640.00    
Cdaudio      Cdaudio                Cdaudio                Kernel        System     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        12,288.00  3,072.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:52:26    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Cdaudio.sys          768.00    
Cdfs         Cdfs                   Cdfs                   File System   Disabled   Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        46,336.00  6,912.00   0.00   2008-04-13 15:14:21    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Cdfs.sys             4,608.00  
Cdrom        CD-ROM Driver          CD-ROM Driver          Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        5,888.00   45,952.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\cdrom.sys            3,328.00  
COMMONFX     COMMONFX               COMMONFX               Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       53,248.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:32:32    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\COMMONFX.SYS         4,096.00  
COMMONFX.SYS COMMONFX.SYS           COMMONFX.SYS           Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       53,248.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:32:32    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\COMMONFX.SYS         4,096.00  
Compbatt     Microsoft Composite Ba Microsoft Composite Ba Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        3,200.00   2,816.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:36    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\compbatt.sys         1,408.00  
ctac32k      Creative AC3 Software  Creative AC3 Software  Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   217,088.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:34:44    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctac32k.sys          4,096.00  
ctaud2k      Creative Audio Driver  Creative Audio Driver  Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        163,328.00 202,240.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:30:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctaud2k.sys          2,944.00  
CTAUDFX      CTAUDFX                CTAUDFX                Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       188,416.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:32:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTAUDFX.SYS          4,096.00  
CTAUDFX.SYS  CTAUDFX.SYS            CTAUDFX.SYS            Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       188,416.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:32:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTAUDFX.SYS          4,096.00  
ctdvda2k     Creative DVD-Audio Dev Creative DVD-Audio Dev Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       203,264.00 0.00   2008-06-05 04:10:31    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctdvda2k.sys         896.00    
CTERFXFX     CTERFXFX               CTERFXFX               Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       45,056.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:30:43    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTERFXFX.SYS         4,096.00  
CTERFXFX.SYS CTERFXFX.SYS           CTERFXFX.SYS           Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       45,056.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:30:43    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTERFXFX.SYS         4,096.00  
ctprxy2k     Creative Proxy Driver  Creative Proxy Driver  Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   4,096.00   0.00   2009-03-03 23:30:33    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctprxy2k.sys         4,096.00  
CTSBLFX      CTSBLFX                CTSBLFX                Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       176,128.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:33:03    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTSBLFX.SYS          4,096.00  
CTSBLFX.SYS  CTSBLFX.SYS            CTSBLFX.SYS            Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       176,128.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:33:03    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\CTSBLFX.SYS          4,096.00  
ctsfm2k      Creative SoundFont Man Creative SoundFont Man Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   139,264.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:28:56    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctsfm2k.sys          4,096.00  
CVirtA       Cisco Systems VPN Adap Cisco Systems VPN Adap Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        384.00     1,600.00   0.00   2003-04-23 09:52:10    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\CVirtA.sys           544.00    
d346bus      d346bus                d346bus                Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        17,024.00  93,312.00  0.00   2004-03-12 15:41:28    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\d346bus.sys          18,048.00 
d346prt      d346prt                d346prt                Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       1,792.00   0.00   2004-03-12 15:41:42    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\d346prt.sys          1,024.00  
Disk         Disk Driver            Disk Driver            Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        18,048.00  8,320.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:46    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\disk.sys             5,248.00  
dmboot       dmboot                 dmboot                 Kernel        Disabled   Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       219,648.00 0.00   2008-04-13 14:44:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\dmboot.sys           1,536.00  
dmio         Logical Disk Manager D Logical Disk Manager D Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        1,280.00   120,960.00 0.00   2008-04-13 14:44:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\dmio.sys             3,072.00  
dmload       dmload                 dmload                 Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       2,560.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:58:15    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\dmload.sys           640.00    
DMusic       Microsoft Kernel DLS S Microsoft Kernel DLS S Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       40,960.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:45:00    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\DMusic.sys           1,280.00  
drmkaud      Microsoft Kernel DRM A Microsoft Kernel DRM A Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        128.00     128.00     0.00   2008-04-13 14:45:13    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\drmkaud.sys          384.00    
E1000        Intel(R) PRO/1000 Netw Intel(R) PRO/1000 Netw Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       120,320.00 0.00   2008-08-20 18:09:39    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\e1000325.sys         2,560.00  
emupia       E-mu Plug-in Architect E-mu Plug-in Architect Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   73,728.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:28:54    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\emupia2k.sys         4,096.00  
Fastfat      Fastfat                Fastfat                File System   Disabled   Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        114,560.00 9,088.00   0.00   2008-04-13 15:14:28    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Fastfat.sys          8,576.00  
Fdc          Floppy Disk Controller Floppy Disk Controller Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        384.00     19,200.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:25    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\fdc.sys              3,968.00  
Fips         Fips                   Fips                   Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,992.00   29,696.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:33:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Fips.sys             896.00    
Flpydisk     Floppy Disk Driver     Floppy Disk Driver     Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        11,776.00  2,048.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:24    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\flpydisk.sys         2,176.00  
FltMgr       FltMgr                 FltMgr                 File System   Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        65,280.00  32,256.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:32:58    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys           7,936.00  
Ftdisk       Volume Manager Driver  Volume Manager Driver  Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        102,400.00 5,888.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:52:41    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ftdisk.sys           4,096.00  
Gpc          Generic Packet Classif Generic Packet Classif Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        512.00     28,416.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:56:32    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\msgpc.sys            1,152.00  
ha10kx2k     Creative Hardware Abst Creative Hardware Abst Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   626,688.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:29:17    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ha10kx2k.sys         4,096.00  
hap16v2k     Creative P16V HAL Driv Creative P16V HAL Driv Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   114,688.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:29:30    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\hap16v2k.sys         4,096.00  
hap17v2k     Creative P17V HAL Driv Creative P17V HAL Driv Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        4,096.00   126,976.00 0.00   2009-03-03 23:29:35    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\hap17v2k.sys         4,096.00  
HidBatt      HID UPS Battery Driver HID UPS Battery Driver Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       15,360.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:37    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\HidBatt.sys          1,792.00  
HidUsb       Microsoft HID Class Dr Microsoft HID Class Dr Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        1,920.00   4,864.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:45:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\hidusb.sys           896.00    
HTTP         HTTP                   HTTP                   Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        99,584.00  94,976.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:53:48    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\HTTP.sys             19,712.00 
i8042prt     i8042 Keyboard and PS/ i8042 Keyboard and PS/ Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        22,784.00  12,160.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:17:59    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\i8042prt.sys         3,840.00  
iaStor       Intel RAID Controller  Intel RAID Controller  Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       267,520.00 0.00   2005-10-12 15:07:10    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\iaStor.sys           3,456.00  
Imapi        CD-Burning Filter Driv CD-Burning Filter Driv Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        19,712.00  11,904.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:57    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\imapi.sys            2,560.00  
intelppm     Intel Processor Driver Intel Processor Driver Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        11,008.00  8,832.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:31:31    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\intelppm.sys         2,816.00  
ip6fw        IPv6 Windows Firewall  IPv6 Windows Firewall  Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        384.00     22,400.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:53:32    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ip6fw.sys            3,968.00  
IpFilterDriv IP Traffic Filter Driv IP Traffic Filter Driv Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        3,456.00   19,840.00  0.00   2001-08-17 16:55:07    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ipfltdrv.sys         2,816.00  
IpInIp       IP in IP Tunnel Driver IP in IP Tunnel Driver Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        2,176.00   11,776.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:57:07    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ipinip.sys           2,688.00  
IpNat        IP Network Address Tra IP Network Address Tra Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        5,888.00   92,672.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:57:10    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ipnat.sys            3,584.00  
IPSec        IPSEC driver           IPSEC driver           Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        1,536.00   62,976.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:19:42    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ipsec.sys            2,944.00  
IRENUM       IR Enumerator Service  IR Enumerator Service  Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        4,864.00   1,664.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:54:28    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\irenum.sys           1,792.00  
isapnp       PnP ISA/EISA Bus Drive PnP ISA/EISA Bus Drive Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        19,328.00  9,216.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:40    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\isapnp.sys           2,048.00  
Kbdclass     Keyboard Class Driver  Keyboard Class Driver  Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        6,528.00   6,912.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:46    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\kbdclass.sys         4,352.00  
kmixer       Microsoft Kernel Wave  Microsoft Kernel Wave  Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        105,600.00 14,592.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:45:07    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\kmixer.sys           3,072.00  
KSecDD       KSecDD                 KSecDD                 Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        64,256.00  10,368.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:31:40    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\KSecDD.sys           2,560.00  
mnmdd        mnmdd                  mnmdd                  Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        1,792.00   0.00       0.00   2001-08-17 16:57:28    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\mnmdd.sys            384.00    
Modem        Modem                  Modem                  Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        20,608.00  1,536.00   0.00   2008-04-13 15:00:18    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Modem.sys            2,560.00  
MODEMCSA     Unimodem Streaming Fil Unimodem Streaming Fil Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        3,968.00   5,760.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:57:37    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MODEMCSA.sys         2,304.00  
Mouclass     Mouse Class Driver     Mouse Class Driver     Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        5,888.00   6,144.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:47    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mouclass.sys         4,224.00  
mouhid       Mouse HID Driver       Mouse HID Driver       Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        2,560.00   3,584.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:47:57    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mouhid.sys           2,432.00  
MountMgr     Mount Point Manager    Mount Point Manager    Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        33,664.00  1,408.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MountMgr.sys         2,816.00  
MRxDAV       WebDav Client Redirect WebDav Client Redirect File System   Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        128,512.00 26,240.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:32:42    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mrxdav.sys           6,912.00  
MRxSmb       MRXSMB                 MRXSMB                 File System   System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        278,272.00 114,432.00 0.00   2008-10-24 07:21:07    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mrxsmb.sys           10,880.00 
Msfs         Msfs                   Msfs                   File System   System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        12,032.00  896.00     0.00   2008-04-13 14:32:38    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Msfs.sys             2,560.00  
MSKSSRV      Microsoft Streaming Se Microsoft Streaming Se Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        3,584.00   384.00     0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:51    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MSKSSRV.sys          1,280.00  
MSPCLOCK     Microsoft Streaming Cl Microsoft Streaming Cl Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        1,536.00   128.00     0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:50    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MSPCLOCK.sys         1,536.00  
MSPQM        Microsoft Streaming Qu Microsoft Streaming Qu Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        1,664.00   0.00       0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:51    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MSPQM.sys            1,152.00  
mssmbios     Microsoft System Manag Microsoft System Manag Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        3,840.00   4,480.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:45    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mssmbios.sys         1,792.00  
MSTEE        Microsoft Streaming Te Microsoft Streaming Te Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        2,560.00   0.00       0.00   2008-04-13 14:39:50    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\MSTEE.sys            512.00    
Mup          Mup                    Mup                    File System   Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        70,912.00  13,952.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:17:05    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Mup.sys              5,632.00  
NABTSFEC     NABTS/FEC VBI Codec    NABTS/FEC VBI Codec    Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        256.00     37,888.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:46:24    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\NABTSFEC.sys         896.00    
NDIS         NDIS System Driver     NDIS System Driver     Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        131,072.00 22,272.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:20:35    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\NDIS.sys             7,552.00  
NdisIP       Microsoft TV/Video Con Microsoft TV/Video Con Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       6,912.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:46:21    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\NdisIP.sys           1,024.00  
NdisTapi     Remote Access NDIS TAP Remote Access NDIS TAP Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       5,504.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:57:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ndistapi.sys         1,280.00  
Ndisuio      NDIS Usermode I/O Prot NDIS Usermode I/O Prot Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        768.00     8,704.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:55:57    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ndisuio.sys          2,048.00  
NdisWan      Remote Access NDIS WAN Remote Access NDIS WAN Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       71,296.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:20:41    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ndiswan.sys          8,192.00  
NDProxy      NDIS Proxy             NDIS Proxy             Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       31,616.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:57:28    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\NDProxy.sys          2,432.00  
NetBIOS      NetBIOS Interface      NetBIOS Interface      File System   System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        12,288.00  14,976.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:56:01    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\netbios.sys          2,432.00  
NetBT        NetBT                  NetBT                  Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        34,048.00  109,824.00 0.00   2008-04-13 15:20:59    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\netbt.sys            6,784.00  
NetMate2     CATC USB/Ethernet Link CATC USB/Ethernet Link Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       25,088.00  0.00   2000-03-07 19:24:27    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\netmate2.sys         1,536.00  
NIC1394      1394 Net Driver        1394 Net Driver        Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       52,096.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:51:22    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\nic1394.sys          2,944.00  
Npfs         Npfs                   Npfs                   File System   System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        21,120.00  1,792.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:32:38    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Npfs.sys             3,584.00  
Ntfs         Ntfs                   Ntfs                   File System   Disabled   Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        412,544.00 96,384.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:15:49    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Ntfs.sys             14,080.00 
Null         Null                   Null                   Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        384.00     0.00       0.00   2001-08-17 16:47:39    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Null.sys             384.00    
NwlnkFlt     IPX Traffic Filter Dri IPX Traffic Filter Dri Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       3,968.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:54:05    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\nwlnkflt.sys         640.00    
NwlnkFwd     IPX Traffic Forwarder  IPX Traffic Forwarder  Kernel        Manual     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        0.00       25,344.00  0.00   2001-08-17 16:54:08    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\nwlnkfwd.sys         1,536.00  
ohci1394     OHCI Compliant IEEE 13 OHCI Compliant IEEE 13 Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   41,216.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:46:18    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\ohci1394.sys         2,432.00  
OMCI         OMCI                   OMCI                   Kernel        System     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        224.00     7,520.00   0.00   2001-08-22 12:42:57    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\OMCI.SYS             1,824.00  
ossrv        Creative OS Services D Creative OS Services D Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        4,096.00   98,304.00  0.00   2009-03-03 23:29:11    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ctoss2k.sys          4,096.00  
Parport      Parallel port driver   Parallel port driver   Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        256.00     67,072.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:09    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\parport.sys          2,944.00  
PartMgr      Partition Manager      Partition Manager      Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        11,648.00  2,048.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:40:48    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\PartMgr.sys          2,560.00  
ParVdm       ParVdm                 ParVdm                 Kernel        Auto       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       1,408.00   0.00   2001-08-17 16:49:49    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ParVdm.sys           2,176.00  
PCI          PCI Bus Driver         PCI Bus Driver         Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        34,176.00  16,000.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:43    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys              5,632.00  
PCIIde       PCIIde                 PCIIde                 Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       896.00     0.00   2001-08-17 16:51:49    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\pciide.sys           128.00    
Pcmcia       Pcmcia                 Pcmcia                 Kernel        Disabled   Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        24,960.00  35,072.00  0.00   2008-04-13 14:36:41    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\Pcmcia.sys           8,064.00  
phaudlwr     Philips Audio Filter   Philips Audio Filter   Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        2,176.00   69,376.00  0.00   2008-05-07 05:40:05    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\phaudlwr.sys         1,024.00  
PptpMiniport WAN Miniport (PPTP)    WAN Miniport (PPTP)    Kernel        Manual     Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       40,320.00  0.00   2008-04-13 15:19:47    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\raspptp.sys          2,048.00  
Processor    Processor Driver       Processor Driver       Kernel        System     Stopped    OK         FALSE       FALSE        10,880.00  8,576.00   0.00   2008-04-13 14:31:29    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\processr.sys         2,816.00  
PSched       QoS Packet Scheduler   QoS Packet Scheduler   Kernel
```

Comment: @Radim: Post the results of a "driverquery" from a command-prompt somewhere. Odds are that most of the drivers can be eliminated from question that way, and whatever is left ought to be a pretty small group to search thru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still doing some checks, but I am >95% sure that the leak was caused by Daemon Tools v3.46.  I had this virtual CD/DVD software installed since 2004, something else had to trigger this leak (a Windows update, etc.).  I removed the Daemon Tools and now the Poolmon tag "Stor" does not show up.  Also, the file atapi.sys is now showing with Microsoft version info, before the uninstall it there was no version info embedded in the file.  Daemon Tools have served me well over the years, but I will remember this pain for a long time :).

Comment: Confirmed, Daemon Tools v3.46 driver was the cause.  I removed Daemon Tools and not the PC has been healthy for several weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I have seen seems to link this to a storage device driver, mostly related to Qlogic or Nvidia RAID setups.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this one:

```
iaStor       Intel RAID Controller  Intel RAID Controller  Kernel        Boot       Running    OK         TRUE        FALSE        0.00       267,520.00 0.00   2005-10-12 15:07:10    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\iaStor.sys           3,456.00
```

I've had no problems with this driver myself.
If I were you, I would try to upgrade/change to a different one.

Comment: iaStor.sys was my original suspect, but it is listed in the poolmon output and seems to have reasonable and stable numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/47251/windows-2003-x64-crashing-with-probably-caused-by-iastor-sys) that had issues with the iaStor, specifically with the Intel ICH9R controller - both hardware/software wise. IMO, an on-board RAID controller is useless. Intel, nVidia, HighPoint whatever. Now, on-board controllers for workstations are all the same: awful. But in the server market it's a little tricker to determine if the on-board solution is the real RAID or not. Personally, whatever equipment you buy you should research the specs to see exactly what you're getting (or getting into).

I'm not sure if you're running RAID or not, but using on-board RAID will ultimately end up causing more headaches then preventing them. If you need RAID for speed (RAID0) on-board controllers or even software RAID is fine by me. But if you need redundancy, get the real thing and buy a PCI-e/PCI-x/whatever-bus-you-have controller with a real processor and RAM (hell even a battery if money isn't a concern). You'll thank yourself later.

Just my two cents. Sorry for the diatribe.